# Failed downloading file. Nginx aio read /path/to/file failed (22: Invalid argument)

Tags: nginx, centos7, file-sharing

On our site we added the ability to download our video files. We use nginx on our servers. 
The weird issue is now that sometimes files are downloadable and sometimes not.

The error we receive in the nginx error.log

```
[crit] 62196#62196: *15951408 aio read "/path/to/storage/files/[unique_filecode].mp4" failed (22: Invalid argument) while sending response to client, client: [client ip], server: storage.example.com, request: "GET /api/download/files/filename.mp4 HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php7.3-fpm.sock", host: "storage.example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/download?file_id=FILE_ID" 
[error] 62197#62197: *15951406 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: [SERVER_IP], server: storage.example.com, request: "GET /api/download/files/filename.mp4 HTTP/1.1", upstream:
```

To start the download we use php and output the headers

```php
$path = /download/files/[unique_filecode].mp4?file_id=[file_id]&ip=[CLIENT IP]&speed=0&mode=1&timestamp=[unix timestamp];

// Speed: Limit the download speed depending on the user type

return response('', 200)->withHeaders([
            'Content-type' => 'video/mp4',
            'X-Accel-Redirect' => $path,
            'Content-disposition' => '"attachment";'
        ]);
```

Our nginx config

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  10240;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  video/mp4;
    server_tokens off;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # file handle caching / aio
    open_file_cache          max=200000 inactive=3m;
    open_file_cache_valid    2m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   on;
    aio on;
    directio 8m;
    directio_alignment 4096;

    access_log off;
    sendfile    on;
    tcp_nopush  on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:20m;
    include conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

```
server {

        listen      80;
        server_name storage.example.com;

        set $storagePath "/path/to/storage";

        location /download/ {
            internal;
            alias $storagePath/;
            limit_conn addr 2;
            set $limit_rate $arg_speed;
        }
}
```

Why does aio throw an `Invalid argument` error? I checked the path and it's correct.

We're currently using CentOS 7 on our storage server.

**EDIT:**

Storage disks are formatted with ext4

```
/dev/sdd1                           ext4      2.7T  2.2T  414G  85% /disk4
/dev/mapper/centos_hosted--by-disk1 ext4      2.5T  2.1T  228G  91% /disk1
```

**EDIT 2:**
Nginx version 1.15.11
Nginx compiled with:
Nginx upload and vod modules are the latest available versions.

```
./configure 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--access-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--with-debug 
--with-http_auth_request_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_mp4_module 
--add-module=../nginx-upload-module 
--add-module=../nginx-vod-module 
--with-file-aio 
--with-threads 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_v2_module
--with-http_realip_module
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
 vod_open_file_thread_pool;
    vod_path_response_prefix '';
    vod_path_response_postfix '';
    vod_segment_duration 20000;
    vod_align_segments_to_key_frames on;
    vod_expires 6h;

    vod_mapping_cache mapping_cache 8m; 
    vod_response_cache response_cache 128m;    
    vod_metadata_cache metadata_cache 4000m;
```

Comment: You set `directio 8m;`. Do files larger than that succeed, and smaller files fail? Or vice versa?

Comment: Do you know your drive's sector size? Googling for your issue returned this post from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54265428/3320401 do you have those unreadable files in different mount points? If so could you add more details from fstab/mount etc?

Comment: @Marco The OP has already done what was specified in that SO answer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton in 99.5% the files are bigger than 50Mb. We store different qualities of our videos on the servers and the user can also choose which one he want to have. Now the weird thing is that the smaller one with around 1.1Gb fails and the bigger one with around 2.3Gb is served without any issues. I downloaded both files through ftp to verify that they are intact and both work. What's also weird is, that some files have this issue other don't.

Comment: I found out that if I hit Refresh in the browser several times, at any point the file is served and I can download it, after that I have to hit Refresh several times till it "works" again. Wasn't able to find a recognizable schema.

Comment: Are you running nginx included in your distro? Since there is still no idea of what's going on, would you try a newer one from nginx.org repos?

Comment: I use a self compiled version. Edited my post with the compiled modules

Comment: I tried a bit and disabled `open_file_cache_*` completly and it seems to work now, tested different files and all started the download.But since we're handling many files the `open_file_cache` option seems mandatory to me. Also it confuses me that this seems to be the error, since on that server are around 15k files stored and the cache seems large enough for my opinion.

Comment: Could it be that the `vod_*_cache` has an impact on the `open_file_cache` option? Edited my post with the vod config

Comment: Consider the possibility that `open_file_cache` is buggy. Do you really need `open_file_cache` at all? Linux does its own caching of directory entries and inodes in RAM, so I would expect the performance gain from this to be minimal, provided the system has enough RAM of course. If you're running up to the limits of your server's RAM then it might possibly help a little, but the solution there is to fit more RAM.

Comment: I researched the option a while ago and from the articles I read it seemed a good idea since there is a lot of requests on the files, but now with the information you provided I guess I can try it without it. The server has 32gb of ram, so I guess this should be enough for first!? 
I will go for it now without the `open_file_cache` option and will keep an eye on the RAM. If the issue should reoccur I will update the thread.